# Create a new reverse list (own class) using vector in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, vector

I have the next code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

class TList {
private:
     std::vector<const char*> elementos;
     int position;
     TList(std::vector<const char*> elementos);
public:
    TList(const char** e, int s);
    TList *GetReverseList();
    int Size();
    const char *Next();
};

TList::TList(const char** e, int s) {
    std::vector<const char*> res (&e[0], &e[s]);
    elementos = res;
    position = 0;
}

TList::TList(std::vector<const char *> elements) {
    std::vector<const char*> res = std::vector<const char*>();
    int size = elements.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        res.push_back(elements.at(i));
    }
    elementos = res;
    position = 0;
}

//Create a new TList with the reverse list of elements
TList *TList::GetReverseList() {
    TList *res = new TList(elementos);
    std::reverse(res->elementos.begin(), res->elementos.end());
    return res;
}

int TList::Size() {
    return elementos.size();
}

//Use the position to get the next char *
const char * TList::Next() {
    const char * res;
    if (elementos.empty()) {
        res = NULL;
    }
    else {
        int pos = position;
        int size = elementos.size();
        res = pos == size ? elementos.at(position - 1) : elementos.at(position);
        if (pos < size) {
            position++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 2;
    const char *arr[2] = {"Hola", "AAAA"};
    TList *list = new TList(arr, size);
    TList *listReverse = list->GetReverseList();
    printf("Size: %u \n", listReverse->Size());
    printf("First value: %s \n", listReverse->Next());
    printf("Second value: %s \n", listReverse->Next());
    delete list;
    delete listReverse;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in Visual Studio it says in the console

```
Size: 2
First Value: AAAA
Second Value: Hola
```

and it throw an exception "ucrtbased.pdb not loaded" "ucrtbased.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module ucrtbased.dll" here is an image:
[image]

and also open this window:

[image]

all of these exceptions are thrown when it try to delete listReverse, here is another capture of the callstack (ignore the additional variables like listCopy): 
[image]

I want to create a new TList as optimized as possible but with its elements reversed, I don't want to do a copy constructor because I need it as a function "GetReverseList" so, what can I do?

Comment: The proper tool for figuring this out is the debugger.

Comment: Is this a homework or why are you coding lists yourself? Did you check [reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) and [reverse_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) from the STL? And please, don't use raw pointers (check the [CppCodeGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-resource)).

Comment: Press retry. And walk up the callstack to your code.

Comment: I am trying to learn how can I create custom methods for string list, and my main problem is because the debug failed so I want to know why it failed

Comment: The code triggered a check that Microsoft graciously put in to catch some invalid memory accesses. It's up to you to have a debugger break there and show you *which* invalid pointer you tried to use. Once you know which pointer, the debugger has all sorts of goodies for figuring out *why* the pointer is invalid.

Comment: I edited the message and put the callstack with the adresses

Comment: On the toolbar in Visual Studio there should be a `Stack Frame:` combo box. Change that to your code after you press Retry on the exception dialog.

Comment: Your callstack picture isn't a callstack. It's the assertion without saying which function triggered it, which function called that one, which called that one, etc. until you eventually reach your code. I'd recommend consulting a VS debugger tutorial. It's possibly the most user-friendly debugger interface and any effort there will pay off immediately and immensely.

Comment: I change the call stack sorry for the delay

Comment: What is on line 33 of your code that contains main().

Comment: I saw the main problem, it is because the "listReverse" of the code is "listReverseOptimizada", the other "listReverse" in the parse is "TList" not "TList*" so when I try to delete it I put "delete &listReverse" and it throw the error, how can I delete a "TList" object?

Comment: It should be `delete listReverse;` not `delete &listReverse;`

Comment: It says "expression myst be a pointer to complete object type" [image](https://imgur.com/a/Bn3aBkb)

Comment: Your image is blocked by my corporate firewall. I can't help now.

Comment: I answer my message so there is the image

Comment: I have just tested the code that is in the question in Visual Studio 2017 and it works without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `elements` as argument in the `TList::TList(std::vector<const char *> elements)` for `elements` had been defined as class member.

The follow `code` could work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
//#include <tchar.h>

class TList {
private:
     std::vector<const char*> elementos;
     int position;
     TList(std::vector<const char*> elementos);
public:
    TList(const char** e, int s);
    TList *GetReverseList();
    int Size();
    const char *Next();
};

TList::TList(const char** e, int s) {
    std::vector<const char*> res (&e[0], &e[s]);
    elementos = res;
    position = 0;
}

TList::TList(std::vector<const char *> ve) {
    std::vector<const char*> res = std::vector<const char*>();
    int size = ve.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        res.push_back(ve.at(i));
    }
    elementos = res;
    position = 0;
}

//Create a new TList with the reverse list of elements
TList *TList::GetReverseList() {
    TList *res = new TList(elementos);
    std::reverse(res->elementos.begin(), res->elementos.end());
    return res;
}

int TList::Size() {
    return elementos.size();
}

//Use the position to get the next char *
const char * TList::Next() {
    const char * res;
    if (elementos.empty()) {
        res = NULL;
    }
    else {
        int pos = position;
        int size = elementos.size();
        res = pos == size ? elementos.at(position - 1) : elementos.at(position);
        if (pos < size) {
            position++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 2;
    const char *arr[2] = {"Hola", "AAAA"};
    TList *list = new TList(arr, size);
    TList *listReverse = list->GetReverseList();
    printf("Size: %u \n", listReverse->Size());
    printf("First value: %s \n", listReverse->Next());
    printf("Second value: %s \n", listReverse->Next());
    delete list;
    delete listReverse;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The class member is `elementos` with an o.

Comment: It gives the same error because the code has "elements" and "elementos" so these are differents variables

Comment: I will try in other windows pc and if I have an error I will think it will be because Windows or Visual studio that need an specific method or something

Comment: @YunbinLiu If the code does not work in Visual Studio, then it really doesn't work properly in Linux -- instead you are relying on undefined behavior.

Comment: I updated the call stack of the error on the message

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I use `g++ -Wall -pedantic-errors `, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that the error is different since as I have commented previously the main problem is the "listReverse" of the code is "listReverseOptimizada", the other "listReverse" in the parse is "TList" not "TList*" so when I try to delete it I put "delete &listReverse" and it throw the error, how can I delete a "TList" object?

Here is the complete code including that element:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

class TList {
private:
     std::vector<const char*> elementos;
     int position;
     TList(std::vector<const char*> elementos);
public:
    TList(const char** e, int s);
    TList(const TList & list);
    TList GetReverseList(TList lstSrc);
    TList *GetReverseList();
    int Size();
    const char *Next();
};

TList::TList(const char** e, int s) {
    std::vector<const char*> res (&e[0], &e[s]);
    elementos = res;
    position = 0;
}

TList::TList(std::vector<const char *> elements) {
    std::vector<const char*> res = std::vector<const char*>();
    int size = elements.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        res.push_back(elements.at(i));
    }
    elementos = res;
    position = 0;
}

TList::TList(const TList & list) {
    std::vector<const char*> el = std::vector<const char*>();
    int size = list.elementos.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        el.push_back(list.elementos[i]);
    }
    elementos = el;
    position = 0;
}

//Create a new TList * with the reverse list of elements
TList *TList::GetReverseList() {
    TList *res = new TList(elementos);
    std::reverse(res->elementos.begin(), res->elementos.end());
    return res;
}

//Create a new TList with the reverse list of elements
TList TList::GetReverseList(TList lstSrc) {
    TList *res = new TList(lstSrc);
    std::reverse(res->elementos.begin(), res->elementos.end());
    return *res;
}

int TList::Size() {
    return elementos.size();
}

//Use the position to get the next char *
const char * TList::Next() {
    const char * res;
    if (elementos.empty()) {
        res = NULL;
    }
    else {
        int pos = position;
        int size = elementos.size();
        res = pos == size ? elementos.at(position - 1) : elementos.at(position);
        if (pos < size) {
            position++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 2;
    const char *arr[2] = {"Hola", "AAAA"};
    TList *list = new TList(arr, size);
    TList listReverse = list->GetReverseList(*list);
    TList *listReverseOptimized = list->GetReverseList();
    delete list;
    delete listReverse;
    delete listReverseOptimized;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to put "delete listReverse" instead of "delete &listReverse" but it doesn't work, here is an image:
[image]

Comment: ***how can I delete a "TList" object?*** You don't. If you don't use new you don't delete. Although with that said you have a leak then because GetReverseList() returns a pointer.

Comment: I put the entire code and the problem is in "delete listReverse;" There is a new inside the GetReverseList so I need to do the delete

Comment: So the the solution is to do what you do in main() in the code that is in the question instead of what you are currently doing in the code on your PC that we can't see. Meaning `listReverse` needs to be a pointer to a TList.